# Как в 1С при выборе файла вывести в поле его адрес + чтобы срабатывал по кнопке?

Tags: 1с

Как в 1С при выборе файла вывести в поле его адрес + чтобы обработчик срабатывал по кнопке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Поле1НачалоВыбораНачалоВыбора(Элемент, ДанныеВыбора, СтандартнаяОбработка)
        Диалог = Новый ДиалогВыбораФайла(РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.Открытие);
    Диалог.Заголовок = "Выберите файл";
    Если Диалог.Выбрать() Тогда
        ДиалогПолноеИмяФайла = Диалог.ПолноеИмяФайла;
        Сообщить(ДиалогПолноеИмяФайла);     
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать асинхронную модель, а не модальную, как у вас. По этой теме куча информации в сети, например:

1. [Диалог выбора файла в 1С и другие диалоги](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-4xNKBcFl8)
2. [Выбор файла и загрузка его на сервер в асинхронном режиме](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/689573/)